# Wordpress child theme loading two duplicate stylesheets

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm writing a child theme as per the specifications in the codex for [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). It seems to work, but when I debug it using Firebug or Chrome's developer toolbar, I see two stylesheets listed. According to the codex:

> style.css is the one and only required file in a child theme. It provides the information header by which WordPress recognizes the child theme, and it replaces the style.css of the parent.

So I'm very confused why I'm seeing style.css #1 and style.css #2. Furthermore, the line numbers listed don't correlate to the file that I'm editing. So something fishy is going on.
I'm working on leecamp.net and the theme is black-board-child (modifying black-board). Can anyone shed light on this?

According to Firebug, two stylesheets are being loaded from the same directory (/themes/black-board-child/). How could this be?

Comment: First check if you have a cache plugin of some sort. Most of the time, they compress your file and make the line numbers you see in the Webdevelopper tools far lower than the real thing. I have no experience with child themes, so I cant help you on that other part.

Comment: There was a caching theme installed! (WP-cache).

Comment: So first part is done. As I said, I'm not used to child theming, so can't help you on that one. Just check the full url of your two styles. Is it EXACTLY the same? If yes, check Header.php. A copy of the css is linked in WP_head(), if you linked it again, that may be why you have 2 css sheets loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if you have a cache plugin of some sort. Most of the time, they compress your file and make the line numbers you see in the Webdeveloper tools far lower than the real thing.
2. Check your `header.php`.  A copy of the CSS is linked in `WP_head()`, if you linked it again, that may be why you have 2 CSS files loaded.